# Regular expression to extract numbers around a slash "/"

Tags: python, regex, string

I tried to extract numbers in a format like `"**/*,**/*"`.

For example, for string `"272/3,65/5"`, I want to get a `list = [272,3,65,5]`

I tried to use `\d*/` and `/\d*` to extract 272,65 and 3,5 separately, but I want to know if there's a method to get a list I showed above directly. Thanks!

Comment: Would you be receiving anything where the numbers *wouldn't* be grabbed? Because if not, `[int(x) for x in re.findall(r'\d+', "272/3,65/5")]` would do the job, and just ignore the `/` and `,` completely (aside from using them to delimit the numbers).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `[0-9]` to represent a single decimal digit. so a better way of writing the regex would be something along the lines of `[0-9]*/?[0-9]+,[0-9]+/?[0-9]*`. I'm assuming you are trying to match fractional points such as `5,2/3`, `23242/234,23`, or `0,0`.

Breakdown of the main components in `[0-9]*/?[0-9]+,[0-9]+/?[0-9]*`:

- `[0-9]*` matches 0 or more digits
- `/?` optionally matches a `'/'`
- `[0-9]+` matches at least one digit

My favorite tool for debugging regexes is https://regex101.com/ since it explains what each of the operators means and shows you how the regex is preforming on a sample of your choice as you write it.

Comment: `\d` works just fine as well (and is non-ASCII friendly IIRC), as long as you use raw strings (which you should always be doing with regex anyway).

Comment: I always lean towards using `[0-9]` because I have never encountered an environment where it didn't work. I must admit though, `\d` is a good deal more readable.

Answer (score 1):

```
#importing regular expression module
import re
# input string
s = "272/3,65/5"
# with findall method we can extract text by given format
result = re.findall('\d+',s)
print(result) # ['272', '3', '65', '5']
['272', '3', '65', '5']
```

where the \d means for matching digits in given input
if we use \d it gives output like below

```
result = re.findall('\d',s)
['2', '7', '2', '3', '6', '5', '5']
```

so we should use \d+ where + matches in possible matches upto fail match